# how to move an object through a grid

Tags: c#, arrays, xna

I'm having trouble coming up with a solution on how to use an array for my snake game. I have a head which is 20x20 pixels on a 400x400 size window.

```
areaGrid = new Vector2[columns, rows];

for (int x = 0; x < columns; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++)
    {
        areaGrid[x, y] = new Vector2(x * 20, y * 20);
        Console.WriteLine("areaGrid[{0},{1}] = {2}", x, y, areaGrid[x, y]);
    }
}
```

So naturally, there will be 400 "blocks" that the head of the snake plus the tail can occupy.  I have the head drawn in the array at [5, 5] which is coords 100, 100 on the grid. I want the head to move 20 pixels at a time which is a new point in the array. So for examply, a movement to the right would place the head at [5, 6] in the array and at 120, 100 on the grid. I just dont know how to do that. How would I implement movement thru an array within my update method?

Comment: [Here](http://forum.chaos-project.com/index.php?topic=12210.0) is snake game implemented and has the functions you might need.

Comment: It's always a good idea to multiply the movement speed by the elapsedTime. So, Position += new Vector2(x * Speed * gameTime.ElapsedTime.TotalSeconds, y * Speed * gameTIme.ElapsedTime.TotalSeconds); This will move it "20 pixels at a second", for example, so you can get much finer control of collisions. Especially if you make a Snake game.

Answer (score 0):

Use a list with the block coords:

```
List<Vector2> Snake = new List() { {5,5}, {5,6}, {5,7}, {6,7}, {7,7} }
```

and to render it:

```
var transform = Matrix.CreateScale(20) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(offset);
SpriteBatch.Begin(null,null,..., tranform);
foreach (var pos in Snake)
  SpriteBatch.Draw(white_1x1_texture, pos, null, SnakeColor);
SpriteBatch.End();
```

or

```
SpriteBatch.Begin();
foreach (var pos in Snake) {
  var box = new Rectangle(offset.X + pos.X * 20, offset.Y + pos.Y*20, 20,20);
  SpriteBatch.Draw(white_1x1_texture, box, null, SnakeColor);
} 
SpriteBatch.End();
```